# Running Netconf in Robot Framework does not return correct output

Tags: robotframework

I have the following errors when trying to execute the netconf command
in Robot Framework. Please let me know if I'm missing/doing something wrong.  Thanks

```
Testcase - Netconf Operation Command in Junos Router

    # Manually turn on netconf in Juniper Networks router
    # command = set system services netconf ssh, commit

    # Juniper Network Router's IP Address
    ${dev_ip} =      Set Variable    192.168.0.1

    ${netconf_cmd}=    catenate     SEPARATOR=
    ...    echo '\\<rpc\\>\\n
    ...        \\<get-interface-information/\\>\\n
    ...    \\</rpc\\>\\n
    ...    ' | sshpass -p a_password ssh admin@${dev_ip} netconf

    ${result} =    Run Process    ${netconf_cmd}    shell=True

    Log To Console    ${\n}Netconf command output: $${result.stdout}${\n}
```

The output is not correct, it simply stores netconf's initial greeting message instead of the output of the data-request.

### Output:

```
Netconf command output: $<!-- No zombies were killed during the creation of this user interface -->
<!-- user regress, class j-superuser -->
<hello xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <capabilities>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:base:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:candidate:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:confirmed-commit:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:validate:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:url:1.0?scheme=http,ftp,file</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:capability:candidate:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:capability:confirmed-commit:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:capability:validate:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:capability:url:1.0?protocol=http,ftp,file</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-netconf-monitoring</capability>
    <capability>http://xml.juniper.net/netconf/junos/1.0</capability>
    <capability>http://xml.juniper.net/dmi/system/1.0</capability>
  </capabilities>
  <session-id>93467</session-id>
</hello>
]]>]]>
<!-- netconf error: unknown command -->
<!-- session end at 2020-05-12 11:02:26 PDT -->
```

Answer (score 0):

From the output message I suspect wrong with the xml input. Please verify the rpc message which as been sent. The response says it an netconf error.

Netconf session is complete with the hello exchange. It failed while sending a rpc